# CSS box-shadow small border on mobile

Tags: css

I'm using a box-shadow to get a color on the outside of a element. On my desktop, this looks fine, but on my mobile, I see a little border, probably caused by the high PPI of my mobile screens. See screenshot below.
[image]

**Code**

```css
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.container.main {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header-main{
  height: 90px;
  box-shadow: 0px -15px 0px 15px #009fe3;
}

.container-row{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #009fe3;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container main">
  <header class="header-main">
      <div class="container-row">
          Put your text here!
      </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: They seem to appear on the other side in Chrome's mobile inspector: https://i.gyazo.com/ec3d512580b09645bab2bc96e32135ce.png

Comment: Why don't you use .header-main{margin-right: -15px; margin-leftt: -15px;} instead of box shadow?

Comment: @Kantoci- This is the mobile layout, when on desktop, the blue solid shadow will be a real shadow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of border if is these your question? Try to: `.header-main {
    background: #009fe3;
}`
Hope these helps.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! The border / glitch is gone!

Answer (score 1):

Box-shadow should be used for off course , box shadow, and not for solid color what you are using. The result can be achieved with out box-shadow also

```
.header-main {
    height: 90px;
    /* box-shadow: 0px -15px 0px 15px #009fe3; */
    background: #009fe3;
}

.container-row {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #009fe3;
    height: 90px;
    margin: -10px -15px;
    padding: 10px 15px 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the mobile layout, when on desktop the blue solid shadow will be a real shadow. That's why I did it this way.